# How to include 3rd party android library code in application source delivered to customer?

Tags: version-control, android-library

I have an application and it is currently using one of the PullToRefresh libraries off of gitub. I've forked that repo, made some changes to better suit my app. I am responsible to give my customer the code for my application, so this would include the library.  What is the recommended way to include it with my application source code (Using SVN for the android app itself).

Answer (score 1):

I imagine at this point, you've long resolved your particular issue.  For future generations, then:

If you're handing the user a zip with a snapshot of the source, include the library source in a subdirectory.  What I have also done to good effect is to build a release bundle archive, which contains all of the different bits needed both binaries and sources.

If you're handing over source code repositories, again you can zip up each repository into a bundle you can hand over.  It's probably worthwhile documenting the upstream for each bit of the project, so the customer can update your fork if they need to.